# How to add extra content in email intent, example:fixed location and real-time and date

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send my fixed location,time and date into the message box using email intent, so far i have only managed to send the email and "TO" who and insert text into the message box and intent to gmail.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.project1.R;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class EmailAuto extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button b;
    private TextView t;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_emailauto );
    }

    public void open(View view) {
        Intent sendintent = new Intent ( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
        sendintent.setType ( "text/plain" );
        sendintent.putExtra ( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Webtime" );
        sendintent.putExtra ( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Date&Time and Location" );
        startActivity ( sendintent);
```

Comment: Have you tried to send both as basic data types? I think you can set the Location either as string (address) or as doubles (latitude and longitude). And you can send the datetime as timestamp in nanoseconds.

Comment: As a string, but how would i do that?

Comment: Option 1: val location = "My location street 123, door 4"
Option 2: val latitude = myLocation.latitude
                val longitude = myLocation.longitude